# "Acpi-State" in slabtop's output gets increased — what is it? Is it a bug?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, acpi

Since boot it gets increased occupying even more RAM than anything else:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 680608 / 719176 (94.6%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 17390 / 17390 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 72 / 113 (63.7%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 78756.64K / 89892.73K (87.6%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.12K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
212109 211201  99%    0.08K   4159       51     16636K Acpi-State
203776 200343  98%    0.06K   3184       64     12736K kmalloc-64
 66682  65275  97%    0.18K   3031       22     12124K vm_area_struct
  7974   3826  47%    0.88K    443       18      7088K xfs_inode
  8596   5811  67%    0.55K    614       14      4912K radix_tree_node
```

---

And after several hours it still grows even larger:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 699321 / 782632 (89.4%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 18711 / 18711 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 72 / 113 (63.7%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 82030.29K / 95484.77K (85.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.12K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
243933 222506  91%    0.08K   4783       51     19132K Acpi-State
231104 210673  91%    0.06K   3611       64     14444K kmalloc-64
 68574  66749  97%    0.18K   3117       22     12468K vm_area_struct
  7218   2706  37%    0.88K    401       18      6416K xfs_inode
  8498   8123  95%    0.55K    607       14      4856K radix_tree_node
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cause of the issue is [UltraKSM](http://kerneldedup.org/projects/uksm/)-related. I have no exact proofs at the moment on hands, but it's very likely.